# How can I switch back to US server (Left 4 Dead 2)?

Tags: steam, left-4-dead-2

I played Left 4 Dead 2 in US before. Then I went to China and played it, it automatically switched to connect local server in China I think.

However, when I went back to US and chose to `play campaign -> play online` again. It shows all campaign games created by Chinese players. It didn't switch back to US server automatically.

Connecting campaign games created by Chinese players in US is very slow.

How can I show campaign games created by American players again? I didn't find any place where I can switch the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the download region for Steam on your PC:
`Steam/Settings/Download+Cloud/Download Region` and set it to United States.

Alternatively you can open game's console menu and enter the command `openserverbroswser` to view available games and their IP addresses. Then, still using the console menu, run the command `mm_dedicated_force_servers [IP]` substituting the `[IP]` with the address of the server you want to play on (no box braces []).

Both of these methods of changing your server are documented on [this Steam discussion](https://steamcommunity.com/app/550/discussions/0/828937546046753049/)